# Maven multi module project - classes not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin

I'm an newbie in maven and tried now for over 2 days to solve my problem. But after the 2 frustrating days I have no idea where the problem could be found. I hope, somebody can help.

First of all the structure of the project:

```
CentwertProject
--- CentwertApp
--- CentwertCore
```

- CentwertProject is just the parent-project for the modules
- CentwertCore is a project with different services
- CentwertApp is the VaadinUI which uses the services from CentwertCore

The problem is, that the dependency works for developing. All classes included in CentwertCore are recognized in the CentwertApp project.
But when I try to debug within Eclipse, the follwoing error is thrown:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [CentwertAppServlet] in context with path [/CentwertApp] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/qufis/CentwertCore/navigation/model/QFNavigator] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.qufis.CentwertCore.navigation.model.QFNavigator
```

QFNavigator is the first class called from CentwertApp which is located in CentwertCore. I have unfortunately no idea to tell maven or eclipse, where the CentwertCore classes could be found.

The pom-File for CentwertProject

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
<artifactId>centwertProject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>centwert-Projekt</name>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>7.5.9</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.source.version>1.8</project.source.version>
    <project.target.version>1.8</project.target.version>
    <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>CentwertCore</module>
    <module>centwertApp</module>
</modules>
```

The relevant parts of CentwertApp pom-file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>CentwertApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>CentwertApp</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
    <artifactId>centwertProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
        <artifactId>CentwertCore</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the relevant parts of CentwertCore pom-file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>CentwertCore</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>CentwertCore</name>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
    <artifactId>centwertProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Thanks

Bernhard

Comment: Submodules in Maven should not have their own versions. Remove those (and I think the relativePath to the parent pom can go too) and see if it helps.

Comment: after removing the version from CentwertCore the dependency within CentwertApp got an error:For artifact {de.qufis:CentwertCore:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

Comment: You should remove the version declaration from the submodules own definition. They will inherit the version tag from the parent. The dependency declarations should still include a version number. For "simplicity" you can just hardcode the same value (1.0-SNAPSHOT), although referencing the parent version would be nicer.

Comment: I did as described, but the situation didn't change. The CentwertCore classes cannot be found.

Comment: The dependency to CentwertCore inside CentwertApp pom-file is useless. You can remove it because it has been already referenced inside module element from your parent pom-file. I give you this clue by looking at ch-multi project from the zip file available at http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip.

Comment: when I remove this dependency, classes (sourcecode) cannot be found anymore.